# Applying styles dynamically for the TreeViewItems inside usercontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I want to apply styles to all RadTreeViewItems in usercontrol from my MainWindow.xaml. I have style related to RadTreeViewItem in resource dictionary and when I try to apply it to usercontrol it is throwing exception.

TreeItemStyle

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                >
    <Style x:Key="GenericTreeItemStyle"  TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:RadTreeViewItem}}" >
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="IsInEditMode" Value="{Binding IsInEditMode,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{Binding NodeFontLook,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="{Binding NodeFontStyle,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Usage in MainWindow.xaml

```
<UC:TreeUserControl Name="RepositoryTree"  Style="{StaticResource GenericTreeItemStyle}"/>
```

It is giving exception

> "'RadTreeViewItem' TargetType does not match type of element 'TreeUserControl'."

How to apply styles to inner controls of UserControl from MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: Make dependency property in user control and bind wanted style to that property. I am not sure how to set that style for the control itself, therefore a comment.